# MongoDB aggregation: How to get the index of a document in a collection depending sorted by a document property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Assume I have a collection with millions of documents. Below is a sample of how the documents look like

```
[
    { _id:"1a1", points:[2,3,5,6] },
    { _id:"1a2", points:[2,6] },
    { _id:"1a3", points:[3,5,6] },
    { _id:"1b1", points:[1,5,6] },
    { _id:"1c1", points:[5,6] },
    // ... more documents
]
```

I want to query a document by `_id` and return a document that looks like below:

```
{
    _id:"1a1",
    totalPoints: 16,
    rank: 29
}
```

I know I can query the whole document, sort by descending order then get the index of the document I want by `_id` and add one to get its rank. But I have worries about this method.
If the documents are in millions won't this be 'overdoing' it. Querying a whole collection just to get one document? Is there a way to achieve what I want to achieve without querying the whole collection? Or the whole collection has to be involved because of the ranking?

I cannot save them ranked because the points keep on changing. The actual code is more complex but the take away is that I cannot save them ranked.

Total points is the sum of the points in the points array. The rank is calculated by sorting all documents in descending order. The first document becomes rank 1 and so on.

Comment: I am looking at change streams. Looks like they may solve my problem.

Comment: how exactly is the rank calculated? is it the position of the document after being sorted by totalPoints?

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ yes. Total points is the sum of the points in the points array. The rank is calculated by sorting all documents in descending order. The first document becomes rank 1 and so on.

Comment: get them in descending order, and use `.forEach` adding one, and if the id is your id, return that one.

Comment: my issue is not in using `$group`. My issue is I want to sort all documents in a collection and get the index of a given document in that collection. Do I have to query all documents do the sorting and get the index or is there a shortcut that does not involve querying all documents just to get one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an aggregation pipeline like the following can get the result you want. but how it operates on a collection of millions of documents remains to be seen.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            docs: {
                $push: { _id: '$_id', totalPoints: { $sum: '$points' } }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$docs'
    },
    {
        $replaceWith: '$docs'
    },
    {
        $sort: { totalPoints: -1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            docs: { $push: '$$ROOT' }
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            docs: {
                $map: {
                    input: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: '$docs',
                            as: 'x',
                            cond: { $eq: ['$$x._id', '1a3'] }
                        }
                    },
                    as: 'xx',
                    in: {
                        _id: '$$xx._id',
                        totalPoints: '$$xx.totalPoints',
                        rank: {
                            $add: [{ $indexOfArray: ['$docs._id', '1a3'] }, 1]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$docs'
    },
    {
        $replaceWith: '$docs'
    }
])
```